# Help to escape solo from K.A.P.O.W. in the Escapists 2

Tags: the-escapists-2

I'm quite stuck in the Escapists with this one, for some reason or another the npc prisoners always seem to raise the suspicion level to dog level, and at this point it's almost always impossible to smuggle anything to create pickaxes/shovels/etc. I've managed to beat it once "by luck" with a teammate, we used the glider escape. It seems unusable alone.

I've tried tunneling from the northern lodge, it just seems very impratical, I've got to dig "quickly" without losing any parts, i've got to consolidate my tunnel to continue AND disable electricity at some points to even get near the wall i got to dig. This seems deliberate from the game to make me try another way.

Sadly i do not find any. I'm not looking for a walkthrough on how to escape, but more for hints or things that might help me to get the dogs less annoying/tips to discover other escape paths. Maybe some item to craft that can help me think outside of the box i'm in.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest escape method is to use the motorcycle in the shack very close south-west of your home-shack (east of the job office, south of the exercise yard).

You will need 40 intelligence and the following items:

- 3 cans of paint
- 1 screwdriver (only one of these which is contraband)
- 1 soda
- 1 sugar mint (the rarest one of these items, but not unobtainable)

Spoiler:

> Go to the shack. You will notice that there is a wall separating you from the motorcycle. But that wall can be easily circumvented by the vent above it. Craft a makeshift ladder from three cans of paint and place it below the vent. Step on the ladder and use the screwdriver to open the vent. You can now traverse the vent to the room with the motorcycle. Craft a "Makeshift Rocket Motor" from the soda and sugar mints. Press "E" to use the bike. Enjoy your freedom.

I didn't do the perimeter escape myself, but I would try this:

1. Find a way to leave the cell at night. Easiest way is through the vent in the bathroom and over the roof. That vent and the roof are a great place to store contraband, by the way.
2. Get to the generator in the main building. You can enter the main building via a roof route, but it requires lots of cutters. Alternative ways might be to obtain the purple key or to pickaxe through the wall.
3. Switch off the generator
4. Leave the generator room the way you came (If you went the roof route: there are several points which allow you to jump down)
5. Cut through the usually electrified fence. If you run out of time cutting, only cut through the first layer and conceal it with a "fake fence" crafted from three wires and finish the escape the next night.